# Unsupported Java Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

It was working Fine But suddenly showing this.

Unsupported Java.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 19.0.1 and Gradle 7.5.

Possible solution:

- Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project

What Should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the exact problem as you,

- Upgrade gradle to version 8.0.2
- JDK 19.0.2

That is all that I changed after creating a new JetPack Compose project.